# how can we use Sobolev embedding to get the following inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, how can we use Sobolev embedding to bound the $L^\infty$ norm of $f$ by its $L^2$ norm and $L^4 \cap L^q$ norm of its derivative, where $\infty>q \gg 1$ is arbitrarily chosen. More precisely, how can we check that
\begin{equation}
\lVert f \rVert_{L^\infty} \lesssim \lVert \nabla  f \rVert_{L^4+ L^q} + \lVert f \rVert_2,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
 \lVert g \rVert_{L^4+ L^q} \triangleq \inf \left\lbrace \lVert g_1 \rVert_4 + \lVert g_2 \rVert_q: g=g_1+g_2, g_1 \in L^4, g_2 \in L^q \right\rbrace.
\end{equation}